# How to get particular string content in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have many select fields with IDs like:

```
"custom_view_custom_conditions_attribute_123_field_id"
"custom_view_custom_conditions_attribute_321_field_id"
"custom_view_custom_conditions_attribute_142_field_id"
```

I can get the id by using this code:

```
id = $(selector).attr("id").replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")
```

But I wanted to get this result **"custom_view_custom_conditions_attribute"**

How can I achieve this in jQuery?

Comment: is `field_ID` is numeric?

Comment: field_id is not numeric.Just a string name.

Comment: What's the bigger picture? Which problem do you want to solve once you have this particular string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
id = $(selector).attr("id").replace(/_[0-9]{3}.*/g, "")
```

It removes any instance of _ + 3 numbers + rest of string.

By the way, `.replace` is pure Javascript, you don't need JQuery

Comment: Thanks so much. But what happens if consist many digits in my example I only show 3 digits but it can be 1 digits or 10 digits?

Comment: @user648198 Simple, remove `{3}`

Comment: Thanks so much. If you can kindly explain what you did in the regular expression would be great so I can learn from it :)

Comment: `_[0-9]{3}.*` 1) begins with _ 2) followed by 3 numbers. 3) followed by null or many characters.  Hope you understood.

Comment: You would want `[0-9]*`.  `*` means match 0 or more. `[0-9]+` would be match 1 or more.

Answer (score 3):

Use RegExp

```
_\d.+
```

like this

```
var id = $(selector).attr("id").replace(/_\d.+/g, '');
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fc3kw/)</kbd>

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan what should be used here i am new to RegExp .

Comment: Actually your regex  seems to be wrong.  I guess [here](http://tinyurl.com/lreswhp) you can see the pictorial representation of your regex.  `match`(similar to `string.match()`) returns the patterns if regex returns true **Does not replace the id instead returns the matched pattern**, where replace is like `string.replace()` in JS.  Since you're a JS guy hope you understood.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan ty for letting me know that i have also updated the answer.

Comment: Simple :)  that it, you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **`regex`**

```
/_\d+_\w*/g
```

1) Begin with _
2) followed by numeric (`+` denotes one or many)
2) again _
4) `\w` followed by alphanumeric (`*` denotes zero or many)

Comment: `\w` includes underscore i.e. it is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and therefore you could simply use `_\d+\w*` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nKBNOx/1)